# starting mysql returns Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: mysql, django

mysql server won't start after upgrading ubuntu with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`  This is a virtual server, 1 vCPU, 1Gb RAM, 25Gb SSD.

Logged in as root and running `systemctl start mysql` yields the following error:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
```

Complete error logs below but i'm currently focused on this line from `/var/log/mysql` it has this statement:

```
2024-02-03T16:49:20.727173Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
```

Complete mysql error log:

```
2024-02-03T16:47:19.670214Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2024-02-03T16:47:19.687660Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-02-03T16:47:21.133578Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2024-02-03T16:47:22.157299Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 21805
2024-02-03T16:47:22.178585Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:47:27.946823Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:48:10.520164Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80035' to '80036' started.
2024-02-03T16:49:20.727173Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE user MODIFY ssl_type enum('','ANY','X509', 'SPECIFIED') NOT NULL; ' failed with error code = 3664, error message = 'Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'.
2024-02-03T16:49:20.796632Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
2024-02-03T16:49:20.804482Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-02-03T16:49:22.378701Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2024-02-03T16:49:23.151447Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 21913
2024-02-03T16:49:23.175839Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:49:28.583673Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:49:47.582932Z 4 [System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '80035' to '80036' started.
2024-02-03T16:50:40.683500Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22014
2024-02-03T16:50:40.748225Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:50:51.055092Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:52:33.503189Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22051
2024-02-03T16:52:33.535441Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:52:44.334823Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:53:03.983546Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22085
2024-02-03T16:53:04.054676Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:53:15.572964Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:55:48.629796Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22130
2024-02-03T16:55:48.663085Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:55:57.179995Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T16:57:20.629157Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22164
2024-02-03T16:57:20.662230Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T16:59:14.196165Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:01:29.180971Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22211
2024-02-03T17:01:29.202871Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:01:44.495647Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:03:46.126331Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22250
2024-02-03T17:03:46.149512Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:04:02.106959Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:07:43.385344Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22300
2024-02-03T17:07:43.405957Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:08:04.717481Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:10:10.953598Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22345
2024-02-03T17:10:10.976282Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:10:29.086610Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:12:32.417613Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22398
2024-02-03T17:12:32.559996Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:13:00.614260Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-02-03T17:17:33.073034Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) starting as process 22461
2024-02-03T17:17:33.131366Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-02-03T17:18:09.787841Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
```

the command: `systemctl status mysql.service` returned:

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Sat 2024-02-03 17:12:28 UTC; 25s ago
    Process: 22381 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 22398 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Tasks: 18 (limit: 1101)
     Memory: 450.8M
        CPU: 6.082s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─22398 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 33.260s CPU time.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 276.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 33.260s CPU time.
Feb 03 17:12:28 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

The command `journalctl -xeu mysql.service` returns:

```
 Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A start job for unit mysql.service has begun execution.
 
 The job identifier is 44626.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Subject: Unit process exited
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
 
 The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 Subject: Unit failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
 Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
 
 The job identifier is 44626 and the job result is failed.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 23.896s CPU time.
 Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 The unit mysql.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 283.
 Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 
 Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
 the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Feb 03 17:30:29 new-django-2022-11-19 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
 Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
```

Comment: from /var/log/mysql/error.log - what does this mean `Failed to delete SDI 'mysql.user' in tablespace 'mysql'.'`